# Geometric interperation of line integral - example

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area

I have hard times figuring out geometric interpretation of line integrals. Here is one example from my book:

Calculate area of cylinder $x^{2}+y^{2}=ax$ sliced with sphere $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=a^{2}$.

Here is sketch of these figures:

http://postimg.org/image/3lra3jgsj/

But what is area to be calculated? Can someone mark it on sketch above?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that really the wording from the book? The only interpretation I can come up with is that it wants the surface area of the section of the cylinder contained in the circle.

Comment: Yes. You mean this area http://postimg.org/image/jk6kb02if/  ?

Comment: I mean, it shouldn't look quite like that (your shading seems to be based on the place where the 2D images you've drawn overlap, rather than the actual 3D intersection). But that's my idea, yes.

Comment: Have a look at [this figure](http://tube.geogebra.org/m/1430881).

Comment: I think I didn't understand term "surface area". In my drawing in first comment ( postimg.org/image/jk6kb02if ) shadings I draw represent area of only "one side" of cylinder, but surface area is total area of figure (in our case cylinder) right? Can we say that surface area of some 3d figure (in our case cylinder) is area of wrapper which surrounds 3d figure?

Comment: PS.  I hope you understand what I mean, English is not my first language but I do my best to explain what I mean.

Comment: I'm not positive that I understand what you mean. It almost sounds to me like you're confusing area and volume. If you look at my figure and imagine discarding the portion of the cylinder that is outside of the sphere, I think you're interested in calculating the surface area of the remaining portion of the cylinder.